# Is "-que" the same as "-ck"?

Tags: spelling, suffixes

Is *-que* the same as *-ck*?

Does it mean something different?

For example, is *cheque* the same as *check*?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Are you asking if the letters "que" and "ck" are always interchangeable in words? Then the answer is no.  There's a noun *check* (which is a piece of paper directing a bank to pay money to s.o.) that is standard American English and that is spelt *cheque* in non US English. If you use *check* as a verb, then the spelling is always "ck"

Answer (score 3):

No, *-que* and *-ck* are not interchangeable in general.

The final *-que* pronounced [k] in English is only found in words of non-Germanic origin, usually French. In French, this is a very common word ending. In English, *-que-* is naturally pronounced [kwi] (the vowel may vary depending on what follows the `e`), but when *-que* is at the end of a word, it is pronounced in a French-like way.

In the word *[cheque/check](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cheque)* meaning a method of payment, both spellings are possible. The meaning is the same. As usual, the French spelling is the standard one in British English while the more phonetic spelling is the standard one in American English. When *[check](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/check)* means *verify* or *verification*, it is always spelled *check*.

Most other words that end in *-que* cannot be spelled another way. In fact, while there are several other *-que/-ck* pairs, I can't think of another one where the two can have the same meaning: others are just different words that happen to have somewhat similar spellings and pronunciation. (Not identical pronunciation: as a rule, the vowel before *-que* is long and stressed, whereas the vowel before *-ck* is short.)

Comment: And sometimes it is found in artificial words, like "deque" in computer science: the name of a double-ended queue data structure which is a deliberate play on "deck".

Answer (score -1):

No these are not same. Cheque is a bill of exchange (used in banking)  by which you order banks to pay someone money from your account. 
It is a verb also that means withdraw money with cheque.

Check- means examine, verify, control, stop or slow down progress of something etc.

Why didn’t they check to make sure it worked ?...checking emails... Sugar solution checks growth of bacteria...etc.

**UPDATE**

Cheque is used not only as a noun but also as a verb and you can verify it [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Cheques)
The website quotes this definition from Random House Webster's College Dictionary 2010, which I think is pretty reliable source of information. Another source is [WordNet 3.1](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=cheque&sub=Search%20WordNet&o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&h=)

Using cheque, a person who has a account in bank can withdraw money from bank, in other words orders the bank to pay the amount. If someone issues you, say a $100 cheque, it is not you but the person who has account with bank is withdrawing money.

Comment: I've never seen "cheque" used as a verb, nor can I readily find a dictionary definition for such a usage.  Can you point out any examples?

Comment: I do agree with you, cheque as a verb is r{arely used... But it is alright to use it as a verb. ,.[Click here] (www.audioenglish.org/dictionary/cheque.htm) for reference.

Comment: The link you give refers to a verb "cheque" in the banking context (withdraw money by writing a check) and not to what you give in your answer. But even in that sense I have never met "cheque" used as a verb. Moreover, I've had a general look at the site you point at in your link and it looks most unreliable to me, obviously done by people whose knowledge of English cannot be trusted, so I would not recommend it to EFL learners.

Comment: @Laure, Dear in what conext did I define "cheque", I did mention cheque is used in banking in brackets. Where else would you withdraw money with a cheque, you will most probably do it in banks. Whether you write a cheque or withdraw money with a cheque, it's just the same because you always have to write the cheque. In case you dont trust that source, may be you would trust [this] and it mentions, cheque is also a verb.(http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Cheques)

Comment: @swapna: A more reliable source, the *OED*, doesn’t mention "cheque" as being use as a verb, at least not my 1994 edition. Neither does my 1984 *Longman's Dictionary of the English Language*. I know language evolves but to this day I've never seen it used as a verb in the press, banks, etc... and anyway this is outside the OP's question.

Comment: @Laure but that website quotes it from  Random House Webster's College Dictionary 2010, which I consider authentic enough. OED Longman Webster all are trusted sources but you won't find modern words everywhere. The way we use words changes everyday and that is how corpus of words expands.

Comment: @swapna You misquoted it. It was from WordNet 3.0, Farlex clipart collection. I recommend reading http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16749/checking-vs-chequing-vs-chequeing-with-regards-to-types-of-bank-accounts. You might want to change your opinion.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that learners use *cheque* as a verbed form of the noun *cheque*.  It's likely to be perceived as nonstandard.  The much more common verb *check* (as in "to check what's under the couch") is never spelled *cheque*.

Comment: @DamkerngT.but in my google chrome, that link opens Wordnet 3.1, I don't know why if that is 3.0  ... I don't say anyone to use it, you should use the words you are most familiar with. I just mentioned in case you encounter it in some text.

Comment: "Cheque" is not okay to use as a verb in spoken language. If you use that spelling, it's passable in written English, by the "anything can be verbed" principle.  (The question is, should you write English that is ineffective when spoken? Sometimes the answer is yes, if it's in a document that will never be read out loud.)